# save datas from firebase to flutter's map

Tags: flutter, dart

i tried to get data from firebase.
i can connect to database and i can display datas in forEach with print.
i created a map outside of forEach blocks. and i tried save data from forEach's element to map.
then i tried display datas with i created map but app returns null.

```
  buildUserSettingField() {

    Map<String, dynamic>? userProfile = {};

    final users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("subscribers").doc("905531235544").snapshots();
    users.forEach((element) { 
      try{
        userProfile = {
          "name" : element["name"],
          "phone" : element["phone"],
          "email" : element["email"],
          "password" : element["password"],
          "date" : element["date"]
        };
      } catch(e) {
        debugPrint("settingERROR: $e");
      }
    });
    print(userProfile["phone"]);
  }
}
```

Comment: does every user has ``phone`` detail added else it'll return ``null`` as it is returning?

Comment: every user has phone data. it has to return phone's value. @OMiShah

Comment: are you getting error with settingERROR tag in the console?

Comment: i dont get any error.  `print(userProfile["phone"]);` this code line returned `null`.

Comment: can you print ``element`` within the foreach block and see if data is not null, possibly ``users`` is null or an ``element`` is  null!

Comment: i already tried it. i printed `element` in foreach block.,i saw data. element is not `null`. what should i do for save data from `element` to `users`.

Comment: i tried to print users in foreach block, and it returned data. but why `users` didnt return data outside of forEach block.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you have async functionality, i.e grabbing data from Firestore, which can take time to complete (returns a future).

I don't see async/await or .then being used which means your print happens before data is populated.